# Image glimmer or sparkle animation

Tags: wpf, xaml, storyboard

I've been searching for awhile, but haven't been able to find anything. I'd like to be able to add kind of a glimmer or sparkly animation on an image element in wpf.

Essentially the effect here I'm after here is the same that you get with trading cards that are "foil's".

I'd like to have an image, and then be able to add this animation to it at will. I'm thinking maybe some kind of user control, or template possibly. Hopefully generic enough that I can just toss an image at it and it will just overlay the image and run.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple construction that easily can be turned into a control is by nesting the image in a Grid and adding a second Grid (on top) as a sibling.

De second grid can be given a linear gradient brush that is primarily transparent but does contain a white glimmer.

This brush can be animated; you could move it and change the opacity of the grid/brush.

This way you do not change the image.